# How to tag user in slack channel from prometheus alert

Tags: alert, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I have alert rule that notify a public channel in a slack. I want to tag people by nicknames that are in the labels of the monitored metrics.
My rule of thumb looks something like this:

```
  - alert: test_alert_tag_v1
    expr: metric_name{instance="<host>", object="<object_name>"} == 1
    for: 1m
    annotations:
      summary: 'Test:'
      description: 'Test: {{ $labels.object }} - {{ $labels.owner }}
    labels:
      slackChannel: '<slack_channel>'
```

Where metric_name has "owner" label. And "owner" looks like @slack.nickname

It works fine with my slack nickname, but doesn't work with other users (mystic).

Can you help pls? Or can you tell what solving is better?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:
match owner with slack dictionary where value is slack memberid
so it looks like

```
description: 'Test: {{ $labels.object }} - <{{ $labels.owner }}>
```

where owner @U012F7F124F
<> - required